# Symfony HttpClient and Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping

I use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient to retrieve the page content because I use a proxy.

```
// Customizing the client
    $this->httpClient = HttpClient::create(
        [
            'proxy' => $connection,
        ]
    );
// I get the content of the page - everything loads normally, in the variable $web string
$web = $this->httpClient->request('GET',  'yandex.ru')->getContent();
```

Forced to string, cast, same on output. $web = (string) $web;

```
// В $this->client / use simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb;
$this->client->load($web);
// result null
```

If I pass simple html dom directly - everything loads fine, it is the Symfony HttpClient format that is not friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$this->client` is a `simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb`, then the [load-method expects a URL](https://github.com/simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom/blob/b8d048e46b7f1964c28ea041d39ccb1d05f9a0ed/HtmlWeb.php#L34)

you probably just want the [HtmlDocument](https://github.com/simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom/blob/b8d048e46b7f1964c28ea041d39ccb1d05f9a0ed/HtmlDocument.php#L108)

```php
$document = new \simplehtmldom\HtmlDocument($web);
```

This is what the `simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb` class returns, if it doesn't return null.

(Also, "web" is a weird variable name for a string of html source code)